# Substring from specific sign to sign

Tags: c#, string, list, substring, trim

I have a list of strings in format like this:

```
Web.WebClient.Areas.Scada.Services.IScadaManualOverrideService,Web.WebClient.TDMSWebApp
```

I need only the part from comma sign to the first dot sign.
For example above it should return this string:  IScadaManualOverrideService

Anyone has an idea how can I do this and get substrings if I have list of strings like first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting strings is not what can be called *effective* solution. Sorry can't just pass nearby.

So here is another one

```
    string text = "Web.WebClient.Areas.Scada.Services.IScadaManualOverrideService,Web.WebClient.TDMSWebApp";
    var end = text.IndexOf(',');
    var start = text.LastIndexOf('.', end) + 1;
    var result = text.Substring(start, end - start);
```

[Proof woof woof](http://dotnetfiddle.net/h48JEx).

*Bullet-proof* version (ugly)

```
    string text = "IScadaManualOverrideService";
    //string text = "Services.IScadaManualOverrideService";
    //string text = "IScadaManualOverrideService,";
    //string text = "";
    var end = text.IndexOf(',');
    var start = text.LastIndexOf('.', (end == -1 ? text.Length - 1 : end)) + 1;
    var result = text.Substring(start, (end == -1 ? text.Length : end) - start);
```

Insert this if hacker attack is expected

```
if(text == null)
    return "Stupid hacker, die!";
```

Comment: Thanks this worked very well. But I found out about different problem. I do have list of strings in something like this format:

"Web.WebClient.Areas.Scada.Services.IScadaManualOverrideService,Web.WebClient.TDMSWebApp"
But I also have few strings in the list that are already like this:
IScadaManualOverrideService, like they are already trimmed.
Is there a possibility to do something with code you wrote to include both cases the one with comma and dot and the one without them? Cause I get an error about Index out of range. (end value goes to -1 in that case).

Comment: It should work for `"IScadaManualOverrideService,"`, but if you don't have comma, then it become really [ugly](http://dotnetfiddle.net/8alT76). See edit.

Answer (score 1):

> from comma sign to the first dot sign

You mean from dot to comma?

You can split the string by comma first, then split by dot and take the last:

```
string text = "Web.WebClient.Areas.Scada.Services.IScadaManualOverrideService,Web.WebClient.TDMSWebApp";
string result = text.Split(',')[0].Split('.').Last(); // IScadaManualOverrideService
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to do it this way. :)

Comment: +1 short & readable. To avoid errors, it is better to replace the index `[0]` with `FirstOrDefault()`, and `Last` with `LastOrDefault()`.

Comment: Thanks. But it's worth noting that the code cannot cause an error. It might give an incorrect result on invalid data but it cannot cause an exception (apart from a `NullReferenceException` if `text` is `null`).

Answer (score 0):

```
    string s = "Web.WebClient.Areas.Scada.Services.IScadaManualOverrideService,Web.WebClient.TDMSWebApp";
    string s1 = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(","));
    string s2 = s1.Substring(s1.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 string input = "Web.WebClient.Areas.Scada.Services.IScadaManualOverrideService,Web.WebClient.TDMSWebApp";
 int commaIndex = input.IndexOf(',');
 string remainder = input.Substring(0, commaIndex);
 int dotIndex = remainder.LastIndexOf('.');

 string output = remainder.Substring(dotIndex + 1);
```

This can be written a lot shorter, but for the explanation i think this is more clear

Answer (score 0):

```
sampleString.Split(new []{','})[0].Split(new []{'.'}).Last()
```

Comment: Split have an Overload with singel char, dont need create array.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "Web.WebClient.Areas.Scada.Services.IScadaManualOverrideService,Web.WebClient.TDMSWebApp";
string subStr = new string(s.TakeWhile(c => c != ',').ToArray());
string last = new string(subStr.Reverse().TakeWhile(c => c != '.').Reverse().ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(last);  // output: IScadaManualOverrideService
```

Comment: Because of inconsistencies. You use at first loop (LINQ), And finally built function (Split).

Comment: Now it's fixed to all linq.